# Close a browser window after redirect (in 2020)

Tags: javascript, java, redirect

I know that closing a browser window/tab is pretty locked down in 2020.  `window.close()` and `self.close()` don't work unless the window was opened up by Javascript in the first place.
Here is the scenario I am trying to handle:

- a client clicks a link in an email
- that link goes to a Java servlet on our site, we record a timestamp
- we redirect the client to a 3rd party partner's video chat
- client talks a bit, then clicks ~'close session'
- our partner then redirects them back to another servlet on our site
- we record another timestamp
- THEN I WOULD LIKE TO JUST CLOSE THE TAB, BUT CANNOT

I've tried a variety of Java HttpServletResponse methods to redirect, but nothing fits the bill.  I've tried the aforementioned js methods and then some, but the browser blocks all attempts.

Is there anything I'm missing here I could try?  I've resorted to just redirecting the client to our homepage for now, but that's not ideal.

Comment: As you noticed, you can't close a web page in any way unless when it is opened by JS, so that is out of the question. Personally I'd just go with a nice "The call has ended" message on the page you're redirecting to.

Comment: @Ivar  :/ yea I guess.. thx